# Waiting for a function to return a value before firing jQuery Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, return

I'm trying to fire an Ajax request with some data being returned by a function call and, as far as I can tell, the Ajax call isn't waiting for my function call to return.

I'm calling `getSelectedMessages` to get the values of a variable number of checkboxes before firing an Ajax request with an array of the values returned by `getSelectedMessages`.

`getSelectedMessages` looks like this:

```
var getSelectedMessages = function() {
    var selected = [];
    $('input:checkbox[name=multipleops]:checked').each(function() {
      selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });
return selected;
}
```

And the Ajax request that's invoking it looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/api/messages/",
   data: { ids: getSelectedMessages(), folder: folder },
   cache: false,
   success: function(){ location.reload() }
});
```

I've done a little bit of searching around and all I'm turning up are answers on how to return a value *from* a call and *to* it.

Comment: look into this `http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/`, this shall probaly do the work.

Comment: It seems that it should work fine. The `data` object is initialised obviously before the Ajax request.

Comment: I don't think we have here enough information to find your bug. Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

`beforeSend` attribute with ajax

try

```
var getSelectedMessages = function() {
    var selected = [];
    $('input:checkbox[name=multipleops]:checked').each(function() {
      selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });
return selected;
}

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/api/messages/",
   beforeSend : function () { return jQuery.isEmptyObject(getSelectedMessages);  }
   data: { ids: getSelectedMessages(), folder: folder },
   cache: false,
   success: function(){ location.reload() }
});
```

Reference

[`beforeSend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
[`isEmptyObject`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/)

Answer (score 0):

Call getSelectedMessages() outside the ajax function of jquery (?)

Answer (score 0):

The function is executed before the request is sent.
The real problem is that the getSelectedMessaged() returns an array.
This results in undefined=undefined after serialization in jQuery's internals.
And that gets ignored by the $.ajax(), so it looks like it's not sending in your vars but it's ignoring them because they're undefined.

If you concatenate a string with the values and make it a query string parameter yourself it should work.
I assume you want to send something like ?var[]=something&var[]=somethingelse to the server, so it ends up in PHP as an array?
Than you'll have to build up the string yourself in the getSelectedMessages function.

Hope it helps,
PM5544

Comment: The function is returning data in the correct format, I've confirmed this by explicitly declaring a global variable and having *getSelectedMessages* set it's value, then passing that into the ajax request

Comment: ah true, i missed the { ids: returnedValue }.
did some more tests and it returns allright indeed.